# Adding gamma and 3-parameter log normal distributions to L-moments ratio diagram lmrd()

Tags: r, distributions, l-moments

How to adapt this piece of code but for:
- gamma distribution
- 3 parameter log normal

More specifically, where can I find the specification of the parameter (lmom) for pelgam() and pelln3()?

Lmom package info just gives: pelgam(lmom), lelln3(lmom), where lmom is a numeric vector containing the L-moments of the distribution or of a data sample.

```
# Draw an L-moment ratio diagram and add a line for the
# Weibull distribution
lmrd()
weimom <- sapply( seq(0, 0.9, by=0.01),
function(tau3) lmrwei(pelwei(c(0,1,tau3)), nmom=4) )
lmrdlines(t(weimom), col='darkgreen', lwd=2)
```

source: http://rgm2.lab.nig.ac.jp/RGM2/func.php?rd_id=lmom:lmrdpoints